# Google Static Maps API: Get more Requests

Tags: google-maps-api-2

i want to use more requests for the Google Static Maps API then 25.000. So i have to take the option requests with a signature. I can't use the combination API key + signature secret for the authentification. I need a client ID. Where can I get this ID? I haven't fount the ID in my account.

Best regards,
Hannes

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [Google Maps APIs - Guides](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/get-api-key?hl=vi#client-id)?

**UPDATE:**

> Your client ID and signature
>
> Upon purchasing your Google Maps APIs Premium Plan license, you will receive a welcome email from Google that contains your client ID and your private cryptographic key.
>
> Your client ID is used to access the special features of Google Maps APIs Premium Plan. In the sample below, substitute YOUR_CLIENT_ID with the client ID you got in your welcome email. All client IDs begin with a gme- prefix.
>
> If you have lost your client ID or private cryptographic key, you can recover it by logging in to the [Google Cloud Support Portal](https://google.secure.force.com/) and clicking Maps: Manage Client ID from the links on the left of the page.

Comment: Thanks, I read the guide, but it wasn't that obvious. I think, I have my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer: I'll need to request the lost client ID from https://google.secure.force.com/. But at first they must create an account for me. I hope this will work. ;)